# Xamarin.Forms WebView, WKWebViewConfiguration, and Sending "Mobile" Headers

Tags: ios, xamarin, ipad, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

I'm getting back into Xamarin.Forms, and I've discovered a new behavior of iOS 13 Safari on the iPad called "Desktop-Class Browsing."  It's covered in detail here:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/203

The problem for me is that I need my Web application to be able to detect if a normal Web browser is viewing it or if it's being viewed by a `Xamarin.Forms.WebView`.  From my Web application, I used to be able to detect a Web view with the user-agent string or with the `X-Requested-With` header.  But if my Web view is running on an iPad on iOS 13, it will enter desktop mode, which yields a desktop Safari user agent a no `X-Requested-With` header, and I can no longer detect that it is a Web view.  This is referenced at 2:56 in the above video.

In a native iOS application, I can apparently use `WKWebViewConfiguration` to control these desktop-like featuers:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebviewconfiguration

I think this is demonstrated at 9:01 in the video in my first link.

How can I use `WKWebViewConfiguration` with Xamarin.Forms?  I see a `WebKit.WKWebViewConfiguration` class, but how can I utilize it with `Xamarin.Forms.WebView`?

Comment: HI, If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you follow the steps in [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/uiwebview-deprecation-xamarin-forms/), your app is using UIWebView instead of a WKWebView

There are several ways of getting access to editing the `WKWebViewConfiguration`:

- You can use a "[Custom Renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/)" to implement your own WKWebView as shown in this [Official Xamarin Forms example](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/85b4e4b0b88593614805c5d9fdc40ff924819363/CustomRenderers/HybridWebView/iOS/HybridWebViewRenderer.cs), and edit the WKWebViewConfiguration there.
- Another possible way that I haven't tried- You can also implement a WKWebView inside your forms using the steps [mentioned here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-views/). And then just edit that property.

Comment: I had to make a custom renderer.  I was already aware of the possibility of a custom renderer and was hopeful to find a different way.

Comment: Ah. Did you try the second option I mentioned above?

Comment: Given the structure of my program, I don't think that option would not be possible.  But I did consider it.  Thank you again.